# how to prevent duplicate in array push in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

my code is like this :

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(item1,item2);
```

so `arr` will contain like:
    ["name","thing1"]

But i got problem when pushing element with same exact value, how do i filter same element value but still accepting update/changes. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AziziMusa/m9e1fkdg/2/)

Comment: You can use jQuery's `grep`. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7364307/4365626)

Answer (score 43):

You can use `arr.indexOf` which returns -1 if it is not found, so you can add it then.

e.g.

```
if (arr.indexOf(item) == -1) {
    arr.push(item);
}
```

However, this does not work in old browsers...

JQuery has a method (`$.indexOf`) that works in every browser, even very old ones.

Answer (score 9):

Just javascript is enough.

If an array contains the item its index is >= 0

so you can do this, if index == -1 , item does not exist in the array, so you can push unique item

```
if(arr.indexOf(item) == -1) {
   arr.push(item);
}
```

**Edit:** 
You asked for changing the number, this is how

```
var index = arr.indexOf(item);
if(index > -1) { //checking if item exist in array
  arr[index]++;   // you can access that element by using arr[index], 
                 // then change it as you want, I'm just incrementing in above example
}
```

Comment: i tried to use this, but not working. And i still want update the number in array, just not push the whole element to end of array

Comment: check the modified example

Answer (score 2):

As what most of the answers have pointed out, you can use the `Array.prototype.indexOf()` method to determine if a value exists or not. In order to check for this, check the array of strings against your `ng-models` value property, `selects.value`, within the `ng-change()` event callback.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m9e1fkdg/3/)**

*Javascript*

```
$scope.goChange = function(name, value){
  if(!~arr.indexOf(value)) {
          arr.push(name, value);
          console.log(arr);
  }
};
```

*HTML*

```
<select ng-model="selects" ng-change="goChange(item.name, selects.value)" ng-options="i as i.value for i in options">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Some implementations can be found as answers to a similar question: [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/angular-js-how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Answer (score 0):

To filter duplicates in an array (es6):

```
let arr = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
Array.from(new Set(arr));
console.log(arr);
// ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```